# Kotlin: correct way for read-only getters

Tags: kotlin

I have a Java class (simplified) like that

```
public class Input {
   private boolean leftPressed;
   private boolean rightPressed;

   public void handleValue(Event event) {
      if (event.button == 1) {
         leftPressed = event.pressed;
      }
      else if (event.button == 3) {
         rightPressed = event.pressed;
      }
   }

   public boolean isLeftPressed() {
      return leftPressed;
   }

   public boolean isRightPressed() {
      return rightPressed;
   }
}
```

Note, that the fields only can be changed by code inside `handleValue`. Would this Kotlin code

```
class Input {
   var leftPressed = false
      private set
   var rightPressed = false
      private set

   handleValue(event: Event) {
      if (event.button == 1) {
         leftPressed = event.pressed;
      }
      else if (event.button == 3) {
         rightPressed = event.pressed;
      }
   }
}
```

be the proper way of creating the read-only properties? You really have to add the `private set` to make it safe/read-only? Are there other/better ways to prevent writing to the field from outside this class?

Comment: Yes. And if they are only used in the same module, you could also make them _internal_ instead.

Comment: This is the best and only way.